# R remove stopwords from text without tokenizing & transforming data into list

Tags: r, text, tidyverse, tidyr, stop-words

I need to remove stopwords from texts without tokenizing or changing the object into a list. I get an error when I use the rm_stopwords function. Can anyone help me out?

```
test<- data.frame(words = c("hello there, everyone", "the most amazing planet"), id = 1:2)
test$words <- rm_stopwords(test$words, tm::stopwords("english"), separate = F, unlist = T)
#Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, words, value = c("hello", "everyone",  : 
  #replacement has 4 rows, data has 2

#I want something like this, where the stopwords are removed but the rest of the formatting remains intact (e.g. punctuation) 

#                words     id
#1    hello  , everyone     1
#2    amazing planet        2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a single regex pattern of all the stopwords with word boundaries and use `gsub` to replace them with blanks.

```
test$words <- gsub(paste0('\\b',tm::stopwords("english"), '\\b', 
                   collapse = '|'), '', test$words)
test
#             words id
#1 hello , everyone  1
#2   amazing planet  2
```

Comment: Can we add few custom words in the stopwords function? For example, if I want to remove planet and hello too.

Comment: You may use `c(tm::stopwords("english"), "hello", "planet")` instead of `tm::stopwords("english")` @SDas

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach that will produce an output similar to that you want. You can use `tidytext` functions to make the filter based on stopwords and then molten the filtered values into a dataframe close to that you expect. Here the code:

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
#Data
test<- data.frame(words = c("hello there, everyone", "the most amazing planet"),
                  id = 1:2,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Unnest
l1 <- test %>% unnest_tokens(word,words,strip_punct = FALSE)
#Vector for stop words
vec<-tm::stopwords("english")
#Filter
l1<-l1[!(l1$word %in% vec),]
#Re aggregate by id
l2 <- l1 %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(text=paste0(word,collapse = ' '))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id text            
  <int> <chr>           
1     1 hello , everyone
2     2 amazing planet
```